# Dropzonejs how to add/delete from server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I know this is a very old issue but honestly I did not find a single complete piece of code for dropzonejs which is working as described. 
I am trying to implement dropzonejs for file uploading. What I need is upload file to the server when it is dragged, and remove the file from the server when Remove file url is clicked. 
I saw many solutions, for me, uploading just works fine. But when I try to implement the remove, I found no sample. 
for the upload process, I configured my dropzone like below:

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function() {
        //upload process
    }
};
```

It shows the addRemoveLink like "Remove file" just under the uploaded file.
I have seen someone to use another property like

```
  Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    removedFiles: function() {
        //remove process
    }
};
```

I am not sure how to implement this. Should I implement this like below? :

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function(){
        //upload process
      }
    removedFiles: function() {
        //remove process
    }
};
```

**Please NB. I am expecting a full working example with server side upload and file delete.**